# Sorted list with alphabetical order

Tags: category, list-view

I have actual the follow code:

```
    <?php 
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$subcategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('level', ['lteq' => $parentCategory->getLevel() + 2])
        /*->addFieldToFilter('level', $parentCategory->getLevel() + 1)*/
        ->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => $parentCategory->getData('path') . '%'])
        ->addAttributeToSelect(['name'])
        ->setOrder('name', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
foreach ($subcategoryCollection as $category): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And I like to have a sorted list, sorted like this:

A

Adidas
Altra

B

Body Glove

D

Dakine etc

I also have the issue, I not need to have the category "Brands" and "View all Brands" in the list.

Comment: What's the output you are getting with your code? Looks it is already sorting as you expected.

Comment: I modyfied my code already, and I get the sorting, but nor the "grouping" by A, B C.

Comment: I like to have it like here:

http://www.outdoorequipped.com/info/our_brands

and I have it like https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands

I know the idea how it could be, but I do not know exactly how to coding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="mega-columns row">
<div class="col-sm12">
<div>
<?php $previous = null;?>
<?php foreach ($subcategoryCollection as $category): ?>
    <?php $name = $category->getName();
          $firstLetter = substr($name, 0, 1);
          if($previous !== $firstLetter){
             echo "</div><div class="row"><h3>".$firstLetter."</h3>";
          }
          $previous = $firstLetter;
    ?>

    echo '<div class="col-sw-4"><a href="'.$category->getUrl().'">'.$category->getName().'</a></div>';
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

This is obviously not the best solution but should work.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745091/how-to-display-an-array-under-alphabetical-letters-using-php)

Comment: It makes a funny output:

A Acorn A Adidas A Altra A Arc'Teryx A Asics B Body Glove

and instead of a, I needed to change to A.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Hi

See my answer below, so far looks not that bad. Only need to create columns and put them on the page...

Any idea how to do?

Kindly Simon

Comment: You just need to wrap it with some div classes. I have updated my answer, few classes might need to change as your css. Give it a try

Comment: Nearly...

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands

only need to see, how I get each "letter" in a row...

Comment: Can you update what you have in your code? It should be in same row.

Comment: I updated my code, right at the moment, I have one "big" row over all.

Comment: Hi Adarsh Khatri

Instead of having a foreach loop, possible to do a while loop? And "pack" as follow together:

The letter, and then the list, eg:

A

Acorn
Adidas
Arteryx

B

Balsen
Bochum

etc

Comment: Try with having `<div class="col-sw-4">` inside `if` statement. I have updated.

Comment: It looks different https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands

But still need to do some modifications...

Comment: Try with my this updated answer.

Comment: Try to understand what's happening, `</div>` suppose to close right before **B* section, in our case it is closing after each row. I would suggest you to play around with it. You will get there.

Comment: Is there a possibility to find out, how many "entries" each "letter" it have?
eg to find out how many brand categories starting with an A?

I think, if I can find out this, then it will be easy to do the loop with an while-loop. Simillar when I do an sql statement directly on a database.

Comment: Try with updated one.

Comment: I updated also one version, and it seems to be like this.

Only need to "format" the css a bit, with margin/padding.

The problem was, in the first time we not need a </div>, as long as $previous == null;
But when the $previous is not same $firstletter, we need a </div>.
And after the foreach loop I put one last </div>.

Comment: the result:

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands

Answer (score 0):

I modified it a bit:

```
    <?php
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$subcategoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('level', ['lteq' => $parentCategory->getLevel() + 2])
        /*->addFieldToFilter('level', $parentCategory->getLevel() + 1)*/
        ->addFieldToFilter('path', ['like' => $parentCategory->getData('path') . '%'])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => '3'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => '129'))
        ->addAttributeToSelect(['name'])
        ->setOrder('name', Varien_Data_Collection_Db::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
?>

<div class="mega-columns row">
<div class="col-sm12">
<div class="row">

<?php $previous = null;?>
<?php foreach ($subcategoryCollection as $category): ?>

    <?php $name = $category->getName();
          $firstLetter = substr($name, 0, 1);
          if($previous == null){
             echo '<div class="col-sw-4">'."\n";
             echo '<h3>'.$firstLetter.'</h3>'."\n";
             $previous = $firstLetter;
          }
          elseif ($previous !== $firstLetter){
                echo '</div>'."\n";
                echo '<div class="col-sw-4">'."\n";
                echo '<h3>'.$firstLetter.'</h3>'."\n";
                $previous = $firstLetter;
          }
          echo '<a href="'.$category->getUrl().'">'.$category->getName().'</a>'."\n";

    ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Only need to "group" it in columns and on the hole page.

Here is the result so far: https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/allbrands